# the meaning of "for"

Tags: meaning, prepositions, for

> 1.The market basket may not be representative, it can overstate or understate inflation **for** certain groups.
>
> 2.CPI does measure the variation in price **for** retail goods and other items paid by consumers, it does not include things like savings and investments.

I find it hard to understand the meaning of the preposition **for**,
when it acts as an adverb, it isn't that difficult,
but when it acts as an adjective , it completely baffles me, like the examples above.

I guess the ***for**s* above are adjectival and modifies the preceding noun ,
but how do I understand or interpret the meaning of these **for**s?

---

Author posted in comment:

If it's an adverb:

> "I bought this **for** you"

"for" here tells the purpose or introduce the people receiving the thing.

That's the meaning I know.

Comment: Can you please provide an example in which you understand the "for"? In the examples you provided, "for" is used with its most basic meaning.

Comment: @virolino If it's an adverb "I bought this for you" , for here tells the purpose or introduce the people receiving the thing. That's the meaning I know.

Comment: No, "for" is neither an adverb nor an adjective. I'm afraid you are using those words wrong.

Answer (score 1):

"For" can be a preposition or a conjunction. I am not sure what you understand by "adjective" or "adverb".

Now let's analyze your examples, from simple to complicated.

You say that you completely understand "for" in this sentence:

> "I bought this **for** you"

I will "simplify" it to:

> bought ... **for** (you)

---

We move to example 1:

> 1.The market basket may not be representative, it can overstate or understate inflation **for** certain groups.

I will "simplify" it to:

> overstate or understate inflation **for** certain groups

and further to:

> overstate ... **for** (certain groups)

which is totally similar with:

> bought ... **for** (you)

---

Moving to example 2:

> 2.CPI does measure the variation in price **for** retail goods and other items paid by consumers, it does not include things like savings and investments.

We simplify it to:

> measure the variation in price **for** retail goods

and further to:

> measure ... **for** (retail goods)

which is again totally similar with:

> bought ... **for** (you)

---

So as you can see, it is a matter of "splitting" the sentence properly, not a matter of changing the meaning of "for".

In all examples we have the structure:

> verb + ... + **for** + (something)